# Building different XML files with same JAXB objects

Tags: java, jaxb

Let's say I want to use JAXB to generate two XML files -- one containing a list of items, the other containing detailed definitions of those items.  For instance, something like this:

Garage.xml:

```
<garage>
    <car ref="1" />
    <car ref="2" />
</garage>
```

Cars.xml:

```
<cars>
    <car id="1" color="blue" model="Impreza" />
    <car id="2" color="plaid" model="Taurus" />
</cars>
```

Is there anything clever I can do to define a single JAXB `Car.java` object that will allow me to use the same object for both files?  If not, is there an accepted best practice anyone would recommend beyond the obvious solution of creating two separate `Car` classes?  (One with the `ref` attribute, the other with the `id`, `color`, and `model` attributes.)

Comment: EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) has an external mapping document extension that allows you to do this:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html (I'm the MOXy lead).